# Shapefile to GeoJson conversion using C#

Tags: shapefile, c#, mongodb

I have some shapefile which I want to convert to GeoJSON and store in MongoDB for querying.

Is it possible to take a shapefile and convert it to GeoJSON format in C#? I have been able to convert shapefiles to GeoJSON from the drivers available online and then import the documents in MongoDB, but I wish to get this all done in C# only. Reason being the ability to let me do some changes to the document on the fly.

If there is no solution available as such, then pointing me in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: As you have found the documentation of GDAL and even which features that have been ported makes it a hard choice. Do you really need to perform this import operation in C#? Is it a once only operation? The command line ogr2ogr that's mentioned in a answer will import the files with a lot less effort.

Comment: He may just want the features added as documents to a collection, as opposed to adding the entire geojson FeatureCollection as a document.  That said, I'm mongodb-ignorant (first time on mongodb was Mon. afternoon) and there may be an easy way to do this after its loaded.

Comment: @Stoner: I want to be able to make changes to the GeoJson i extract from the shapefile. When using ogr2ogr i get a GeoJson file which is of type Features. I wish to extract each feature separately and put it as a document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was working on something close to this morning (except my source is PostgreSQL) and I'm coming at it from the [GDAL C# bindings](http://fwtools.maptools.org). But I haven't worked it out yet. Most of the posts (not recent) mention implementing the ogr2ogr.cpp in .NET.  But I'm hoping someone posts something more recent.

For testing, this would be what you would call from the command line (and this is what we both want from c#):
`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON outshp.json c:\temp\us_counties_.shp`

This gets the Geometry JSON, and you could probably build out the rest and get the full GeoJSON feature.  But I don't know if there is something that already exists in the c# bindings.

```
        [TestMethod()]
        public void WriteGeoJSONTest3()
        {
            string shapeFilePath = @"c:\temp\us_counties_.shp";

            OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.RegisterAll();
            Driver drv = Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");

            var ds = drv.Open(shapeFilePath, 0);

            /*
            Driver geoJSONDriver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("GeoJSON");

            string geojsonfilepath = @"c:\temp\us_counties_test.json";

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(geojsonfilepath))
                System.IO.File.Delete(geojsonfilepath);

            geoJSONDriver.CreateDataSource(@"c:\temp\us_counties_test.json", null);
            */

            OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0);

            OSGeo.OGR.Feature f;
            layer.ResetReading();

            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); 

            while ((f = layer.GetNextFeature()) != null)
            {
                var geom = f.GetGeometryRef();
                if (geom != null)
                {
                    var geometryJson = geom.ExportToJson();
                    sb.AppendLine(geometryJson);
                }
            }

            Trace.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            Assert.IsNotNull(sb.Length > 0);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are looking after GDAL/OGR library. Have a look at http://www.gdal.org/ogr_apitut.html ogr vector tutorial and http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp

Comment: Thanks for the link. This library is very poorly documented though.

Answer (score 0):

Before you begin, follow the steps:

- In Manage NuGet Packages, install GDAL and GDAL.Native
- Move GdalConfiguration.cs to App_Start folder in your project
- In Global.asax.cs add this

  ```
  protected void Application_Start()
      {                  
        ...

          GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
        ...

      }
  ```

You are okay to continue now...

Answer (score 0):

If you want features with properties as an `FeatureCollection` you can use this.

```
public string ShpToGeoJSON(string Inputpath)
    {
        GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();
        GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
        OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.RegisterAll();
        OSGeo.OGR.Driver drv = Ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile");
        DataSource ds = drv.Open(Inputpath, 0);

        OSGeo.OGR.Layer layer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0);
        OSGeo.OGR.Feature f;
        layer.ResetReading();

        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb.AppendLine("{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\", \"features\":[");
        while ((f = layer.GetNextFeature()) != null)
        {
            //Geometry
            var geom = f.GetGeometryRef();
            if (geom != null)
            {
                var geometryJson = geom.ExportToJson(new string[] { });
                sb.Append("{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":" + geometryJson + ",");
            }

            //Properties
            int count = f.GetFieldCount();
            if (count!=0)
            {
                sb.Append("\"properties\":{");
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    FieldType type = f.GetFieldType(i);
                    string key = f.GetFieldDefnRef(i).GetName();

                    if (type == FieldType.OFTInteger)
                    {
                        var field = f.GetFieldAsInteger(i);
                        sb.Append("\"" + key + "\":" + field + ",");
                    }
                    else if (type == FieldType.OFTReal)
                    {
                        var field = f.GetFieldAsDouble(i);
                        sb.Append("\"" + key + "\":" + field + ",");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var field = f.GetFieldAsString(i);
                        sb.Append("\"" + key + "\":\"" + field + "\",");
                    }
                    
                }
                sb.Length--;
                sb.Append("},");
            }

            //FID
            long id = f.GetFID();
            sb.AppendLine("\"id\":" + id + "},");
        }
        
        sb.Length -= 3;
        sb.AppendLine("");
        sb.Append("]}");
        
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```